# Potential Well with Spin Orbit Coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I want to calculate the Eigenenergies of a finite potential well with spin orbit coupling. What I did first was look at the case of the infinite potential well.
What I'm starting with is a Hamiltonian of the form:
$$ H = H_{0}+ H_{Rashba} = -\frac{\hbar²}{2m}\Delta +\frac{\alpha}{\hbar}\sigma_{z}p_{x} $$

Calculating the Eigenvalues of this Hamiltonian yields:
$$ E_{\uparrow\downarrow} = \frac{\hbar²k_{\uparrow\downarrow}²}{2m}\mp \alpha k_{\uparrow\downarrow}$$
This gives me then 4 different **k** values:

$$ k_{\pm \uparrow} = \frac{m}{\hbar}(\pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha²}{\hbar²}+ 2E_{\uparrow}/m}+\alpha) \\
k_{\pm \downarrow} = \frac{m}{\hbar}(\pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha²}{\hbar²}+ 2E_{\downarrow}/m}-\alpha) $$

I now consider the Potential:
$$ H = -\frac{\hbar²}{2m}\Delta +\frac{\alpha}{\hbar}\sigma_{z}p_{x} + V(x) $$

Where inside the infinite potential well I have $$V(x) = - V_{0}$$
And the width of my well is **a**.
I'll skip the remaining calculations because the boundary conditions are fairly straight forward and what I get in the end is:
$$ \mathbf{E_{\uparrow \downarrow} = \frac{\pi²\hbar²n²}{2ma²} - \frac{\alpha²m} {2}}$$

Now I'm trying the same thing for the **finite Well** and this is where I get stuck.
The Ansatz for my Wave function is for the region outside the well:

$$ \Psi_{\uparrow\downarrow}(x) = Aexp[i\kappa_{+\uparrow\downarrow}x]+B[i\kappa_{-\uparrow\downarrow}x]$$

where $$ \kappa_{\pm \uparrow} = \frac{m}{\hbar}(\pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha²}{\hbar²}+ 2E_{\uparrow}/m}+\alpha) \\
\kappa_{\pm \downarrow} = \frac{m}{\hbar}(\pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha²}{\hbar²}+ 2E_{\downarrow}/m}-\alpha) $$

Inside the well

$$ \Psi_{\uparrow\downarrow}(x) = Aexp[ik_{+\uparrow\downarrow}x]+B[ik_{-\uparrow\downarrow}x]$$

where $$ k_{\pm \uparrow} = \frac{m}{\hbar}(\pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha²}{\hbar²}+ 2(V_{0}+E_{\uparrow})/m}+\alpha) \\
k_{\pm \downarrow} = \frac{m}{\hbar}(\pm \sqrt{\frac{\alpha²}{\hbar²}+ 2(V_{0}+E_{\downarrow})/m}-\alpha) $$

And my Potential looks like:
 $$ \begin{align}
V(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
0 \qquad &x < -a/2 \\
-V_{0} \qquad & -a/2 < x < a/2 \\
0 \qquad &x > a/2
\end{cases}
\end{align} $$

For now I'm an only interested in Solutions where $-V_{0}<E<0 \\$

What I realized is that inside and outside the well I have Solutions of basically the same form i.e. complex exponentials.
The finite case could be solved analytically and for the infinite case of a potential well **without** SO I can solve the problem by numerically solving a transcendental equation. But what should I do now?

With my boundary conditions I now get 8 equations (4 per spin):
$$ Ae^{-i\kappa_{+\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} + Be^{-i\kappa_{-\uparrow\downarrow}} =Ce^{-ik_{+\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} + De^{-ik_{-\uparrow\downarrow}a/2}$$ $$  
\kappa_{+\uparrow\downarrow}Ae^{-i\kappa_{+\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} + \kappa_{-\uparrow\downarrow}Be^{-i\kappa_{-\uparrow\downarrow}} =k_{+\uparrow\downarrow}Ce^{-ik_{+\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} + k_{-\uparrow\downarrow}De^{-ik_{-\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} $$

$$ Ce^{ik_{+\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} + De^{ik_{-\uparrow\downarrow}} =Ee^{i\kappa_{+\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} + Fe^{i\kappa_{-\uparrow\downarrow}a/2}$$

$$ k_{+\uparrow\downarrow}Ce^{ik_{+\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} +k_{-\uparrow\downarrow}De^{ik_{-\uparrow\downarrow}} =\kappa_{+\uparrow\downarrow}Ee^{i\kappa_{+\uparrow\downarrow}a/2} + \kappa_{-\uparrow\downarrow}Fe^{i\kappa_{-\uparrow\downarrow}a/2}$$

I tried typing in those equations into mathematica which looks something like:

*Solve [{A Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "+UP"] a/2] + 
    B Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "-UP"] a/2] == 
   C Exp[-I Subscript[k, "+UP"] a/2] + 
    D Exp[-I Subscript[k, "-UP"] a/2], 
  A Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "+DOWN"] a/2] + 
    B Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "-DOWN"] a/2] == 
   C Exp[-I Subscript[k, "+DOWN"] a/2] + 
    D Exp[-I Subscript[k, "-DOWN"] a/2], 
  Subscript[[Kappa], 
      "+UP"] A Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "+UP"] a/2] + 
    Subscript[[Kappa], 
      "-UP"] B Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "-UP"] a/2] == 
   Subscript[k, "+UP"] C Exp[-I Subscript[k, "+UP"] a/2] + 
    Subscript[k, "-UP"]  D Exp[-I Subscript[k, "-UP"] a/2], 
  Subscript[[Kappa], 
      "+DOWN"] A Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "+DOWN"] a/2] + 
    Subscript[[Kappa], 
      "-DOWN"] B Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "-DOWN"] a/2] == 
   Subscript[k, "+DOWN"] C Exp[-I Subscript[k, "+DOWN"] a/2] + 
    Subscript[k, "-DOWN"]  D Exp[-I Subscript[k, "-DOWN"] a/2], 
  C Exp[-I Subscript[k, "+UP"] a/2] + 
    D Exp[-I Subscript[k, "-UP"] a/2] == 
   G Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "+UP"] a/2] + 
    F Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "-UP"] a/2], 
  C Exp[-I Subscript[k, "+DOWN"] a/2] + 
    D Exp[-I Subscript[k, "-DOWN"] a/2] == 
   G  Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "+DOWN"] a/2] + 
    F Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "-DOWN"] a/2], 
  Subscript[k, "+UP"] C Exp[-I Subscript[k, "+UP"] a/2] + 
    Subscript[k, "-UP"]  D Exp[-I Subscript[k, "-UP"] a/2] == 
   Subscript[[Kappa], 
      "+UP"] G Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "+UP"] a/2] + 
    Subscript[[Kappa], 
      "-UP"]  F Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "-UP"] a/2], 
  Subscript[k, "+DOWN"] C Exp[-I Subscript[k, "+DOWN"] a/2] + 
    Subscript[k, "-DOWN"]  D Exp[-I Subscript[k, "-DOWN"] a/2] == 
   Subscript[[Kappa], 
      "+DOWN"] G Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "+DOWN"] a/2] + 
    Subscript[[Kappa], 
      "-DOWN"]  F Exp[-I Subscript[[Kappa], "-DOWN"] a/
        2]}, {Subscript[energy, "+UP"]}]*

(I know it's unreadable here but I defined every wave vector for mathematica and wanted to solve for one of the energies)

Can you help me out here? It looks like I'm not able to determine the eigen- energies with mathematica since it's taking too long to find some solution.
Where do I go from here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a physics question, but rather a question about how to solve a transcendental equation in Mathematica. You can take the following steps:

1. Pack all the coefficients into a vector $v=(A,B,C,D\cdots)^\intercal$.
2. Rewrite the equation as into the matrix form like $M(E).v=0$, by packing all the  factors like $e^{ik}$ into the matrix $M(E)$. Note that $M(E)$ is a function of the energy $E$.
3. The problem of solving the transcendental equation is mapped to the problem of finding $E$ to make the determinant of $M(E)$ vanish, i.e. $\det M(E)=0$.
4. Define a function `f[E_]:=Det[M[E]]` and use `FindRoot` to search for solutions of $E$.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure about some things:
I'm dealing with a non-square matrix and can't find the determinant unless I just ignore 2 of my equations (?) Using only 6 equations I can find a determinant but I have 2 unknowns left inside my matrix and I can't just use some numerical value for one of my energies.
How am I supposed to use FindRoot then ?
$(FindRoot[Det[M] == 0, {Subscript[energy, "DOWN"], -V }]$ Will give me an error saying that my determinant is not a number with dimension {1}. This error vanishes when using a numerical Value for $E_{\uparrow}$ but the energies are unknown.

Comment: @holdsworthy Your matrix is not square because you only have four equations for six variables, but this is because you did not include the boundary condition. You need to include two boundary conditions A=0 and F=0, then you have a square matrix, and the det is well-defined.

Comment: I don't see why A and F should be zero. Which boundary condition would that be?

Comment: @holdsworthy All eigenstates of your Hamiltonian can be classified into two classes: **bound states** (if $E<0$) or **extended states** (if $E>0$) (where $E$ is the eigenenergy and "0" stands for the potential energy at $x=\pm\infty$). If you are looking for an extended state, any energy $E>0$ is an eigenenergy, and you do not need to solve for $E$. If you are looking for a bound state, then the energy is quantized, because you need to impose the boundary condition that the wave function can not diverge exponentially as $x\to\infty$, which means $A=F=0$.

Comment: Thanks again so far. I think I'm almost there. It took me some time to figure out that I need to have $$\frac{\alpha²}{\hbar²}+ 2E_{\uparrow}/m < 0$$ to get exponentially decaying solutions in the limit.
I now did the calculation with a slightly different coordinate system to make it a bit easier (the well now is defined between x=0 and x=a) and I end up with the following coefficient matrix: http://i.imgur.com/RjFFzbm.png

Comment: My problem now is that when using **FindRoot[Det[M] == 0, {y, -V }]** I only always get one solution that is exactly equal to the starting point I put in as a parameter. Can you help me out with that? I'm using numerical values for my constants and the solution I get only seems to depend on the chosen starting point. No matter what values I use for $\alpha$, $\hbar$, m, a.
I'm pretty sure this is not correct since it looks like I have infinitely many solutions where I should have quantized bound states instead.

Comment: Using **NSolve[Det[M] == 0 && -V <= y < 0, y]** gives me different solutions depending on my chosen parameters m, a etc. which is a good thing but I'm not sure if this makes any sense because I get the following Plot when using **Plot[Det[M], {y, -V, 0}]** :
http://i.imgur.com/qedgIQ5.png
Which looks like a continous set of solutions instead of a quantized one.

What am I missing here?